# How to access member variable?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a function that looks like this:

```
void myClass::memberStruct::memberFunction() {
         // code
}
```

I then have a (protected) array in `myClass`, that I want to access in this function(not a static array). How do I access this array? I can't use `this` because that gives me a pointer to the `memberStruct`.

Comment: There's no `myClass` instance here. The only instance, `*this`, is a `memberStruct` as you have noted.

Comment: Please don't edit profanity back into your question.

Comment: `myClass` and  nested `memberStruct` are two completely unrelated types. Nested class declarations are just syntactic sugar. You cannot access any non-static members of `myClass` from an object of `memberStruct` type unless you somehow pass and object of `myClass` type to the point of access. Your array exists only in `myClass` objects. Unless you have a `myClass` object, there's no array to access.

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes

Comment: @Quentin 
 
 
Why though? The structs only exist within the context of the class, so every struct must have a class associated with it. Why can't I access that class?

Comment: @AnT 
 
 
Why though? The structs only exist within the context of the class, so every struct must have a class associated with it. Why can't I access that class?

Comment: @sdgdf: No. Your struct type is simply declared withing class declaration, meaning that the only consequence of that is that you now have to refer to your struct type as `myClass::memberStruct`. There are no other consequences. `myClass` and `myClass::memberStruct` are still two independent types that live their independent lives. If there's a tighter relationship between them, then it is in something you are not showing us.

Comment: @AnT Ah okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access rights is not the issue. A nested class has the same access rights as any other member of the class.

The issue is that you don't have an object of `myClass`. Without that, you can't access any member of the class.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **11.7 Nested classes** **[class.access.nest]**
>
> 1 A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11)
>   shall be obeyed. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class E {
>     int x;
>     class B { };
>
>     class I {
>       B b; // OK: E::I can access E::B
>       int y;
>       void f(E* p, int i) {
>         p->x = i; // OK: E::I can access E::x
>       }
>    };
>
>  int g(I* p) {
>      return p->y; // error: I::y is private
>    }
>  };
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

---

The following program works fine for me using g++ 4.9.3.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
   public:

      myClass(int in) : var1(in) {}

      struct memberStruct
      {
         int foo(myClass& obj);
      };

   protected:

      int var1;
};

int myClass::memberStruct::foo(myClass& obj)
{
   return obj.var1;
}

int main()
{
   myClass obj1{10};
   myClass::memberStruct obj2;
   std::cout << obj2.foo(obj1) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the `struct` has nothing to do with the `class`, even though you define the `struct` in the `class`.

Declaring the `struct` in the `class` only limits its scope to the class, nothing else. So no, you can't access the array.

You could however pass the array to the `memberFunction`, for example.

Comment: Or make the nested class a friend.

Comment: @NathanOliver Or that :)

Comment: @NathanOliver that would solves the `protected` access issue, but not the absence of a suitable `myClass` instance.

Comment: @Quentin Ah yes.  The function still needs an instance to work on.

Comment: @NathanOliver That isn't necessary since C++11 - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types - _"Declarations in a nested class can use any members of the enclosing class, following the usual usage rules for the non-static members. (Since C++11)"_

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That does not apply here since the array is not static.

Comment: Why though? The structs only exist within the context of the class, so every struct must have a class associated with it. Why can't I access that class?

Comment: @sdgdf It is not that the class only exist inside the outer class.   Only it's name is scoped to the outer class.  You could have an instance of the class in `main`.

Comment: @sdgdf Well if the name is public then it is really simple.  If it is private then you would have to return an instance of the inner class to `main`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah okay gotcha, Thank you!

Comment: @NathanOliver Oops. Kinda missed that part :)